# Showing video from Visual Studio MVC 4.5 projectfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

If I relate to a video file from Visual Studio MVC 4.5 project folder, it would not start og show correctly. Why? Can I fix it?

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="~/Video/SeducIntro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it:

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="@Href("~/Video/SeducIntro.mp4")" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: The problem was Chrome dont support mp4 video anymore.